# esperar tiempo para que carguen los componentes y mostrar pagina

Tags: angularjs, timeout

Hola estoy trabajando en angularjs en un proyecto que tiene incluido TWINESOCIAL en el cúal muestro redes sociales, este lo tengo dentro de un section en la vista:

`<div class="">
 <script id="twine-script" src="//apps.twinesocial.com/embed?app=prontoweb&showNav=yes&autoload=no"></script>
</div>`

y para llegar a el desde otra vista utilizo:

`$location.path('/Bienvenido');
 $location.hash('feed');`

esto esta asignado en el controlador de la vista con `ng-click`

el tema es que carga muy rapido y no permite cargar el `javascript` y me lanza este error:

[image: error]

investigue y encontré dentro de la librería de angularjs `$timeout` pero nose si me servira, ustedes que recomiendan? saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Te dejo un ejemplo, al darle ejecutar después de 5 segundos se actualiza la variable datos en el scope.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function callAtTimeout() {
   $scope.datos='prueba';
}, 3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  {{datos}}
  </div>
</div>
```

yo uso ésto en AngularJS (Angular 1) y funciona de lujo.

Pd: te dejo la doc. oficial https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Comment: el script generado por twinesocial para mostrar las redes sociales lo tengo en la vista, y yo ordeno que haga el link desde el controlador

Comment: listo lo adapte a angular, yo lo utilizo para mostrar timeouts y demás, si necesitas que haga algo varias veces también está $interval, que ejecuta la función cada intérvalo de tiempo. Saludos

Comment: tambien utilizo el $timeout y funciona de maravilla...

Comment: gracias amigo veremos que tal

Comment: te actualice el ejemplo, dale ejecutar, espera 5 segundos y verás que actualiza el scope.